# Check HTTP Image path if valid

Tags: java

I have a question in Java how can I check if an image http path is valid or existing?

For example:
This image is existing.
http://g0.gstatic.com/ig/images/promos/homepage_home.png

But this one is not.
http://sampledomain.com/images/fake.png

I would like to make a logic such that:

```
If(image is existing)
 - do this
Else
 - do others
```

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Tried it with this code that I got while googling:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class TestImage {
      public static void main(String[] arg){
          Image image = null;
          try {
              URL url = new URL("http://g0.gstatic.com/ig/images/promos/homepage_home.png");
              image = ImageIO.read(url);
          } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("Error");
          }
      }
}
```

But I always get an error...I am not sure if this is possible.. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to check if it exists or if it is a valid URL? I guess the first?

Comment: Hi, I want to check if there really is an image at that path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an Http [Head](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEAD_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods) request. If it's an existing path you'll get a response back, otherwise you'll get an error.

This does not check that it is a valid image though, just that the path exists.  If you want to check whether the image is valid, I think you have got no choice other than to download it.

Comment: Hi, I want to check it in java alone only.  Thanks

Comment: The only way to check that there really is an image at the path is to make a request to the server.

Comment: Hi Jeff..this is actually what I want to know if I could do this in java.. Say I could just supply a url and then check if there is an image behind that.  I am looking at the URL class right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the image exists or not using selenium javascript executor.

Hope this code helps you -

picPath is the Url path you want to validate.

```
 result = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
              "var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); http.open('HEAD',arguments[0], false); http.send();return http.status!=404;", picPath);
```